# input sound detection for raspberry pi

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian, alsa, iot

I am trying to detect/record sound using raspberry Pi,looks like raspberry pi supports audio out but not in,Please can some one suggest better USB soundcard and microphone available for raspberry pi.

BR,
&Sanumala

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. Please use following site for your question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: I use an usb card : creative sound blaster S81140, but yes this have nothing to do with programming. And i use a microphone composite (alimented via battery).

Comment: I've not tried microphones, but probable an USB microphone compatible with Debian should work inside RPi...

Answer (score 0):

There are currently two good GPIO sound cards which allow audio input and have microphones built in :
[The audio injector sound card](http://www.audioinjector.net/#!/rpi-hat) (has great support)
and [the Cirrus Logic audio card.](http://au.element14.com/wolfson-microelectronics/cirrus-logic-audio-card/cirrus-logic-audio-card-for-raspberry/dp/2448312)

You can find a partial list of sound cards for the Raspberry Pi on eLinux. Search for RPi_Expansion_Boards#Sound.